# Adding Process To Fragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have a search bar inside my 'main' layout, i call this layout by returning it with fragment acitivity after calling by my "MainActivity.java".
My question is, how can i add function for the searchbar so i will be able to search from my database? i can only display the layout and i don't know where do i need to put my function for searching data from my database.here is my code from my 'main.java'

```
public class Main extends Fragment{
    public Main(){}

    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
       return rootView;
   }    
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to extends ActionBarActivity and add the search as one the action item in the Actionbar , or toolbar in new V7 widget to take advantage of new material design ?

use the searchview  widget, google  recommend that you insert the search widget as an action view in the Action Bar

[image]

Comment: Please explain more what to do. This almost looks like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I suppose the questioner know how to use searchview widget otherwise where is the searchbar come from in the first place  ?

Comment: I suppose you're supposing good (but that way of thinking could be applied to a lot of SO questions). Still, a bit of code is always better than a "can you try this" answer IMHO.

Comment: is that so , why don't you contact questioner , to see what he need , I can not be simply throwing irrelevant code around !!

Comment: I flagged the question as unclear. I only tried to make *your* answer more relevant and useful, keep calm.

Comment: SearchView widget is another area with wide interest  , questioner may be phrase as seachbar in this context.